# Missing SVN Checkout option

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have just installed tortoiseSVN in windows 8. I want to checkout a folder using the same but when I right click on the folder, I cannot see the SVN Checkout option in the menu dropped. I have used the same in windows 7 and I could see the option for SVN Checkout on right clicking the folder, where I checked out a folder succesfully. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the TortoiseSVN menu contains all the usual options except "Checkout"? Can you please be more specific? And, why the "git" tag?

Comment: Yes, the SVN checkout option is missing, I put the git tag just as maybe guys using git may also help, sorry if it confusing, I will have to remove it for that

Comment: May I ask what menu options you see? Is it like "Create repository here" or like "Update / Commit..."?

Comment: It has worked, I needed to upgrade the working copy since I installed a newer version of tortoise in the windows 8 machine, the folder was transferred from another working copy(already checked out) in the windows 7 machine so I didn't need to checkout again, what I didn't know, I can now see the all the options like commit and update. Thanks for the discussion @Alvaro G.

Comment: You obviously cannot checkout on a working copy, but TortoiseSVN displays a very clear ["SVN Upgrade working copy" menu item](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/tortoise_workingcopyupgrade.html) on older working copies. If you had mentioned that you'd had obtained an answer within seconds. Please don't be so reluctant to provide info ;-)

Comment: I had similar problem below link helped me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715303/svn-error-previous-operation-has-not-finished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "SVN Upgrade working copy" is telling you that:

- That folder already contains a working copy.
- That working copy belongs to an older format and needs to be upgraded.

Since you already have a working copy there's no need to perform a checkout (thus you'll never be offered such option). And if you click on "SVN Upgrade working copy" TortoiseSVN will upgrade the working copy for you so you can start using it (that's a mandatory step).

Comment: I've just had a problem with TortoiseSVN. It suddenly stopped showing anything other than "SVN Upgrade working copy". But I've upgraded WC to 1.7 long ago, so selecting "Upgrade" threw an error stating that my WC wasn't pre-1.7. Well, duh. Installing the latest TortoiseSVN (1.8.2) fixed that issue.

Answer (score 9):

if you unable to see check out option svn working folder already there 
go to folder option and select show hidden files you see the svn folder delete it 
after deleting when you right click you see the option for check out

Answer (score 1):

Some time will happen for because of this.

Please un check the following check box 
**"Setting -> General -> Context Menu -> Hide Menus for unversioned paths"**

Answer (score 1):

Look for **.svn** folder by enabling "Show hidden files and folders" & delete that folder.
In my case it is on C: drive because of which i am not able to see svn checkout option on right click.
It works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting show hidden files did not work for me. 
Right clicking on the SVN folder did not give me the "SVN Checkout" option. Instead, right click on the Windows desktop and the option "SVN Checkout" should be available, then adjust to the appropriate paths/locations you need, and choose OK. This worked for me.